# Creating Singleton class in Python and counting the number of instances

Tags: python

I was trying to understand how to create a Singleton class in Python. Below is how i attempted

```
class Singleton(object):
    _instance = None

    def __new__(class_, *args, **kwargs):
        if not isinstance(class_._instance, class_):
            class_._instance = object.__new__(class_)
        return class_._instance

class MyClass(Singleton):
    num_of_instances = 0
    def __init__(self, real = 5, imaginary = 6):
        self.real = real
        self.imaginary = imaginary
        MyClass.num_of_instances += 1

a = MyClass(10, 20)
print(a.real)
print(a.imaginary)
b = MyClass()

print(MyClass.num_of_instances)  # 2
```

Ideally `__new__()` calls `__init__()` with the object instance, but in the above case when I am trying to create second object `b`, `__new__` won't be called because an instance of `MyClass` already exits then why does the print statement printing `num_of_instances` print `2`?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6760685/1222951) for a proper Singleton implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__new__` is called *for every `MyClass(...)` call*. If it didn't get called, it would not be able to return the singleton instance.

And when the `__new__` method returns an object and that object is an instance of the `cls` argument passed to `__new__` (or a subclass), then the `__init__` method is also called.

So, for each `MyClass(...)` call, `__new__` is called. The `__new__` method always returns an instance of the current class, so `__init__` is called, every time. It doesn't matter here that it is the same instance each time.

From the [`__new__` method documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__):

> If `__new__()` returns an instance of `cls`, then the new instance’s `__init__()` method will be invoked like `__init__(self[, ...])`, where `self` is the new instance and the remaining arguments are the same as were passed to `__new__()`.

You can see this happen if you add some `print()` calls in the methods:

```
>>> class Singleton(object):
...     _instance = None
...     def __new__(class_, *args, **kwargs):
...         print(f'Calling {class_!r}(*{args!r}, **{kwargs!r})')
...         if not isinstance(class_._instance, class_):
...             print(f'Creating the singleton instance for {class_!r}')
...             class_._instance = object.__new__(class_)
...         return class_._instance
...
>>> class MyClass(Singleton):
...     num_of_instances = 0
...     def __init__(self, real=5, imaginary=6):
...         print(f'Calling {type(self)!r}.__init__(self, real={real!r}, imaginary={imaginary!r})')
...         self.real = real
...         self.imaginary = imaginary
...         MyClass.num_of_instances += 1
...
>>> a = MyClass(10, 20)
Calling <class '__main__.MyClass'>(*(10, 20), **{})
Creating the singleton instance for <class '__main__.MyClass'>
Calling <class '__main__.MyClass'>.__init__(self, real=10, imaginary=20)
>>> b = MyClass()
Calling <class '__main__.MyClass'>(*(), **{})
Calling <class '__main__.MyClass'>.__init__(self, real=5, imaginary=6)
```

You can't prevent the automatic `__init__` call, at least not without overriding something else. If you want to avoid `__init__` being called each time, you have some options:

You don't have to use an `__init__` method on the subclass. You could invent your own mechanism, `__new__` could look for a `__singleton_init__` method and call that:

```
class Singleton(object):
    _instance = None

    def __new__(class_, *args, **kwargs):
        if not isinstance(class_._instance, class_):
            class_._instance = object.__new__(class_)
            if hasattr(class_._instance, '__singleton_init__'):
                class_._instance.__singleton_init__(*args, **kwargs)`
        return class_._instance
```

or your `__init__` method could check if there are already attributes set in `vars(self)` (or `self.__dict__`) and just not set attributes again:

```
class MyClass(Singleton):
    def __init__(self, real=5, imaginary=6):
        if vars(self):
            # we already set attributes on this instance before
            return
        self.real = real
        self.imaginary = imaginary
```

The `__new__` and `__init__` logic is implemented in `type.__call__`; you could create a [*metaclass*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses) that overrides that logic. While you could simply call `__new__` only (and leave everything as is), it makes sense to make the metaclass responsible for handling the Singleton pattern:

```
class SingletonMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcls, *args, **kwargs):
        cls = super().__new__(mcls, *args, **kwargs)
        cls._instance = None
        return cls

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance
```

then use this not as a base class but with `metaclass=...`. You can create an empty base class if that's easier:

```
class Singleton(metaclass=SingletonMeta):
    pass

class MyClass(Singleton):
    # ...
```

The above will call `__new__` on the class, optionally followed by `__init__` on the resulting instance, just *once*. The `SingletonMeta.__call__` implementation then, forever after, returns the singleton instance without further calls:

```
>>> class SingletonMeta(type):
...     def __new__(mcls, *args, **kwargs):
...         cls = super().__new__(mcls, *args, **kwargs)
...         cls._instance = None
...         return cls
...     def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
...         print(f'Calling {cls!r}(*{args!r}, **{kwargs!r})')
...         if cls._instance is None:
...             cls._instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
...         return cls._instance
...
>>> class Singleton(metaclass=SingletonMeta):
...     pass
...
>>> class MyClass(Singleton):
...     def __init__(self, real=5, imaginary=6):
...         print(f'Calling {type(self)!r}.__init__(self, real={real!r}, imaginary={imaginary!r})')
...         self.real = real
...         self.imaginary = imaginary
...
>>> a = MyClass(10, 20)
Calling <class '__main__.MyClass'>(*(10, 20), **{})
Calling <class '__main__.MyClass'>.__init__(self, real=10, imaginary=20)
>>> MyClass()
Calling <class '__main__.MyClass'>(*(), **{})
<__main__.MyClass object at 0x10bf33a58>
>>> MyClass() is a
Calling <class '__main__.MyClass'>(*(), **{})
True
>>> MyClass().real
Calling <class '__main__.MyClass'>(*(), **{})
10
```

Comment: @Martjin In this scenario how can avoid reinitialization of the object ?

Comment: @ankit: added that to the answer.

Comment: *"You can't prevent the automatic `__init__` call."* Umm, that's pretty misleading. You can't avoid the automatic `__init__` call ***if*** you implement your singleton logic in `__new__`. There are other solutions that don't have this problem with `__init__` being called.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: you can't prevent the `__init__` call being called when `__new__` returns an object for which `isinstance(cls, returnvalue)` is true. I never made claims about different singleton approaches. *pretty misleading* is a rather harsh tone there, buddy!

Comment: @Aran-Fey: and I've now added an alternative.

Comment: Well, I thought the "you can't prevent it" might sound like generalization to some people. Of course you and I know that it's only true in the context of `__new__`, but less experienced python users might not. So I thought it was worth clarifying. It's good that you've added an alternative.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Need your help here please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72456961/python-class-singleton-pass-the-multiple-argument-to-check-comparison